# How to escape special characters while using request.query in express 4.0

Tags: node.js, api, express

My API server running in express 4 uses **request.query** to read all parameters.

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.search);
});
```

And the request is as follows

```
http://localhost:8080/api?id=123&search=node js&lang=en
```

The value of **request.query.search** is **"node js"** i.e with space. Is request.query escaping special characters like space to %20 ? or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass value in query string you have to use escape() method

```
var url="http://localhost:8080/api?id=123&search="+escape("node js")+"&lang=en";
```

When you retrive value in nodeJS you have to use unescape() method

```
var search= unescape(request.query.search);
```

Comment: The request is received from the browser and not made from an application.